# Mean Median Mode lines showing only in last graph in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to show the `mean`, `median`, and `mode` lines in two graphs but they are only visible in the last graph:

```
#Cut the window in 2 parts
f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (0.2, 1)})
#plt.figure(figsize=(10,7));
mean=df[' rating'].mean()
median=df[' rating'].median()
mode=df[' rating'].mode().get_values()[0]
plt.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.axvline(median, color='g', linestyle='-')
plt.axvline(mode, color='b', linestyle='-')
plt.legend({'Mean':mean,'Median':median,'Mode':mode})

sns.boxplot(df[" rating"], ax=ax_box)
sns.distplot(df[" rating"], ax=ax_hist)

ax_box.set(xlabel='')
```

Comment: See also [How to plot a mean line on a distplot between 0 and the y value of the mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307440/how-to-plot-a-mean-line-on-a-distplot-between-0-and-the-y-value-of-the-mean) for drawing such lines up till the kde curve.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The command `plt` uses the current axis, not all defined axes. To plot something on a specific axis, you have to tell matplotlib/seaborn, which axis you mean:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({" rating": [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10], "dummy": range(10)})

f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw= {"height_ratios": (0.2, 1)})
mean=df[' rating'].mean()
median=df[' rating'].median()
mode=df[' rating'].mode().values[0]

sns.boxplot(data=df, x=" rating", ax=ax_box)
ax_box.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
ax_box.axvline(median, color='g', linestyle='-')
ax_box.axvline(mode, color='b', linestyle='-')

sns.histplot(data=df, x=" rating", ax=ax_hist, kde=True)
ax_hist.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--', label="Mean")
ax_hist.axvline(median, color='g', linestyle='-', label="Median")
ax_hist.axvline(mode, color='b', linestyle='-', label="Mode")

ax_hist.legend()

ax_box.set(xlabel='')
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

If you have a whole bunch of subplots, you approach this task with a loop:

```
f, bunch_of_axes = plt.subplots(200)
...
for ax in bunch_of_axes:
    ax.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
    ax.axvline(median, color='g', linestyle='-')
    ax.axvline(mode, color='b', linestyle='-')
```

If you don't have the axes objects available (for instance, you created your figure using pandas plotting or similar), you can address this problem with:

```
....
bunch_of_axes = plt.gcf().axes
for ax in bunch_of_axes:
    ax.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--', label="Mean")
    ....
```

Update 2021: I changed the pandas code because `get_values()` is now deprecated.
Seaborn has also deprecated [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html). The alternatives are [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), a figure-level function with no ax parameter, or [`histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) which behaves slightly different from `distplot`.

I have summarized now in another thread [how to emulate the old `distplot` behavior with `histplot`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638590/emulating-deprecated-seaborn-distplots)

Comment: `.get_values()` is now deprecated. I used `df[' rating'].mode().tolist()[0]` and it worked. Trying to use `.values()` resulted in 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

Answer (score 12):

Shorter one (using `jupyter notebook`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
sns.displot(xgb_errors, kde=True, rug=True)
plt.axvline(np.median(xgb_errors),color='b', linestyle='--')
```

Comment: Very good answer, this works the best and is more concise than the other answer!