# How to plot a mean line on a displot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot mean line using **displot**. I am trying to replicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307440/how-to-plot-a-mean-line-on-a-distplot-between-0-and-the-y-value-of-the-mean) example but getting error.

```
    from matplotlib import pyplot

g = sns.displot(data=df, x='age', kind="kde", hue="attrition", palette="crest", fill=True,alpha=.7, linewidth=0,)

g.fig.set_figwidth(15)
g.fig.set_figheight(5)
kdeline = g.lines[0]

mean = x.mean()
height = np.interp(mean, kdeline.get_xdata(), kdeline.get_ydata())
g.vlines(mean, 0, height, color='crimson', ls=':')
g.set_ylim(ymin=0)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-86084b5eb03a> in <module>
      5 g.fig.set_figwidth(15)
      6 g.fig.set_figheight(5)
----> 7 kdeline = g.lines[0]
      8 mean = x.mean()
      9 height = np.interp(mean, kdeline.get_xdata(), kdeline.get_ydata())

AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'lines'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `plt.axvline(mean)`. Please see the below example with the `planets` dataset:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('planets')
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='year', kind="kde", hue="method", palette="crest", fill=True,alpha=.7, linewidth=0,)
g.fig.set_figwidth(15)
g.fig.set_figheight(5)
mean = df['year'].mean()
plt.axvline(mean)
```

[image]